# JQuery functions/triggers not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, safari

I have tried playing with jquery functions and triggers for radio, checkbox, and date picker. The sample is below

1. Radio Button

   ```js
   $("input[name=receivedFluStatus]:radio").change(function () {
    reqdEntered = true;
    //alert('radio selected');
    if (this.id=='receivedFluOutside') {
      alert(this.id);
     //alert('receivedFluOutside selected');
     //enableLocation();
     locationEntered = false;
        dateReceivedEntered = false;
       }
       else {
       alert(this.id);
        //alert('receivedFluOutside not selected');
        //disableLocation();
        locationEntered = true;
        dateReceivedEntered = true;
       }

     
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div style='display: block;'>
                   <label>
                       <input type='radio' name='receivedFluStatus' id='receivedFluFrom'>I have received a flu vaccination
                   </label>
               </div>
       <div style='display: block;'>
                   <label>
                        <input type='radio' name='receivedFluStatus' id='receivedFluOutside'>I have received a flu vaccination
                   </label>
               </div>
   ```
2. Checkbox

```js
$("input[name=acknowledge]:checkbox").change(function() {
  //alert('acknowledge selected');
  var acknowledged = $('#acknowledge').is(':checked');
  alert(acknowledged);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='display: block;padding-left: 10px;'>
  <label for='acknowledge' style="font-weight: 400;">
<input type='checkbox' name='acknowledge' id='acknowledge' value='acknowledge'> By checking this box I acknowledge
  </label>
</div>
```

3. Datepicker

```js
 

   $("#outsideDate").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        console.log('date Entered'+dateText);
        dateReceivedEntered = true;
  $('#outsideDateErrorLabel').attr('style','display:none;color: red;font-weight: 200;');
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    outsideDateFocus();
  }
});

function outsideDateFocus() {
 if($('#outsideDate').val()=='MM/DD/YYYY' || $('#outsideDate').val()==''){
  dateReceivedEntered = false;
  $('#outsideDateErrorLabel').attr('style','display:initial;color: red;font-weight: 200;');
 }else{
  dateReceivedEntered = true;
  $('#outsideDateErrorLabel').attr('style','display:none;color: red;font-weight: 200;');  
 }
  alert(dateReceivedEntered);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;padding-left: 30px;">
  <label id="outsideDateLabel" for="outsideDate" style="display:block;color: lightgrey;font-weight: 400;">Date Received:</label>
  <input id="outsideDate" type="text" name="outsideDate" value="MM/DD/YYYY" style="display:block;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: lightgrey;color: lightgrey;" readonly="readonly">
  <label id="outsideDateErrorLabel" for="outsideDate" style="display:block;color: red;font-weight: 200;">This is a required field, please enter date received</label>
</div>
```

The jquery version is 1.9.1 and the load type is onLoad. All the above works just fine in jsfiddle and I tried with all browsers and all devices. Though the above does not work on load type head.

But when I add the above functions  in my application which is a NodeJS app with ui in Jquery none of them work in ios safari and works intermittently in chrome

I looked into how jsfiddle renders onLoad or body load types and I tried the following too

1. Added the entire jquery scripts under a script tag on index.html

   ```
    //<![CDATA[
      window.onload = function () {
    all the scripts here
     //]]>
    }
   ```

But then the handlers for radio/checkbox, datepickers are not invoked

If we add  in the head tag, the handlers work intermittently in chrome but not in iOS safari

Can anybody please help me look into it

Comment: If your using jQuery, you don't need to worry about `window.onload`,  with jquery you can get DomReady etc by placing your code inside a jquery init callback..  eg.. `$(function () { alert("dom ready"); /*other code here*/} );`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/